# how to upgrade to angular2 official release from rc6 from webpack

Tags: angular

I am using rc6 from angular class angular2 starter.  How do I update angular to the latest angular?  Its there a command that will update for me or do I have to manually change versions in package.json?

```
npm update
```

Comment: In package.json change 2.0.0-rc6 to 2.0.0. 
run npm install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two possible ways by which you can update to latest angular.

- By updating package versions manually from [quick start guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)
- By following steps as per [RC4 to RC5 Migration](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html) which will also update to latest angular as per command `npm install @angular/{core,common,compiler,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic} --save`