# angular 2.0 cli project no exported mng 'RouterConfig'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

I started an angular 2.0 project with angular CLI; but when I tried to use routing it is throwing some errors. Currently when I try to run 'npm serve' the error showing is -

"The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler] failed with:
Error: Typescript found the following errors:
  H:/codes/animeSquad/tmp/broccoli_type_script_compiler-input_base_path-XUPT7Vob.tmp/0/src/app/app.routes.ts (5, 10): Module '"H:/codes/animeSquad/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported mng 'RouterModule'."

My package.json content is as such -

```
{
    "name": "anime-squad",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "angular-cli": {},
    "scripts": {
        "start": "ng serve",
        "postinstall": "typings install",
        "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
        "test": "ng test",
        "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
        "e2e": "protractor"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
        "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
        "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
        "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
        "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.7",
        "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
        "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
        "systemjs": "0.19.31",
        "zone.js": "0.6.12"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.10",
        "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
        "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
        "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
        "karma": "0.13.22",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
        "protractor": "3.3.0",
        "ts-node": "0.5.5",
        "tslint": "3.11.0",
        "typescript": "1.8.10",
        "typings": "1.3.1"
    }
}
```

My target is to enable routing while keeping the CLI setup. I am fairly new to angular so simple detailed explanation will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try re-installing...

Comment: same problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"@angular/router" : "^3.0.0-rc.1"` with angular rc5 and if possible try with latest version of angular release as **angular 2.0.0** is released.
You can see answer of question to update to latest angular version :
[how to upgrade to angular2 official release from rc6 from webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507181/how-to-upgrade-to-angular2-official-release-from-rc6-from-webpack/39507676)

Answer (score 0):

RC.2 is shipped with the RC router, which has been deprecated. You need to install the vladivostok router :)

`npm remove @angular/router --save` // will remove the RC router
`npm install @angular/router@3.0.0-alpha.7` --save // will install the latest router